# Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined at setTransitionEndSupport

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have problem with bootstrap. I'm using Node js version 9.7.1 and node package manager version 6.4.0. I have something problem after run the query node app.js on my command-line .

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined at 
setTransitionEndSupport (util.js:55) at util.js:171 at bootstrap.js:9 
at bootstrap.js:10
```

Comment: You need to load jquery first before bootstrap. So, please check this once.